# Is there a shortcut to launch the PyCharm debug command line?

Tags: debugging, command-line, pycharm, shortcut

I can open the debug command line in PyCharm by

1. Tools > Open debug command line, or
2. Console > Show Python Prompt Icon

But is there a shortcut to open this? Couldn't find it on SO or the Pycharm documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PyCharm professional 2016.3.2, is it possible set a shortcut to open debug command line. 
Go to

```
Settings->Keymap
```

and write in search bar `open debug command line`.

Click on this option and if you don't have set the shortcut, you can do it with right click on it and press on `Add keyboard shortcut`.

Comment: Glad to help you!